# PayPal IPN Port and HTTPS

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have checked StackOverflow for an answer to my question and found similar questions but no answer. A least not relating to my question. Sorry If I missed something.

I have set up an IPN consumer which works in a Sandbox environment. When I go live to a none sandbox environment the consumer code does not get hit by the IPN POST.

IPN is enabled and the account is verified.

The differences between my sandbox environment and the live site is as follows:-

Sandbox: Hosted on a dedicated HTTP site on port 80. (http://x.x.x.x/Consumer).
Live: Hosted on a virtual HTTPS site port 443. (https://x.x.x.x/virtual/Consumer).

Have I misunderstood something? Does IPN work on https/Port 443. Do I need to implement some sort of certificate management?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Br
Nigel